# HERE MapView with polylines freezes

Tags: android, here-api

We are reading a GeoJson file (approx. 2.2 MB) with line strings from our server and then in our app we read the GeoJson and create MapPolyline objects out of it, which we then on the map. Evertyhing works ok and the map is responding to touch events normally.

Then after a while, 10-15 minutes (app is visible all the time and nothing is done with it) the map starts lagging really bad. The user cannot browse or zoom the map anymore. Hiding the polylines from the map restores the usability of the map as well as going away from the app and returning into it. The app itself responds normally, but the HERE mapview is eventually completely frozen.

How to prevent this from happening?